# lodash template doesn't return compiled text file

Tags: javascript, xml, lodash

This is my code for creating the template:

```
xmltest = _.template(xmltemplate, {
    id: this.id,
});

console.log(xmltest);
```

This is the xml that I'm using for my template:

```
<Element id="<%- id%>">

</Element>
```

I simplified it, just to make my job easier and it still doesn't work...
This is what it logs in chrome

```
function (obj) {
obj || (obj = {});
var __t, __p = '', __e = _.escape;
with (obj) {
__p += '<Element="' +
__e( id) +
'">\n\n    </Element>\n';

}
return __p
}
```

I'm missing something...
Thanks for the help

Comment: @SLaks, thanks, wow I'm amazed at my mistake, I've been trying to figure it out for an hour...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A compiled Lodash template is a function that runs the template.

If you want to get the result, you need to call that function.